# Dispatching to Swift protocol extension

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Why does the following code print "BaseP" at #2?

```
protocol BaseP { func foo() }
extension BaseP { func foo() { print("BaseP") } }
protocol SubP: BaseP {}
extension SubP { func foo() { print("SubP") } }

class C: SubP {}
let subP1: SubP = C()
subP1.foo()   //  #1 prints "SubP", fine.

class BaseC: BaseP {}
class SubC: BaseC, SubP {}
let subP2: SubP = SubC()
subP2.foo()   //  #2 prints "BaseP". why?
```

In both cases we call `foo()` on a reference with a static type of `SubP`,
referencing an object with a dynamic type that is a class conforming to `SubP`.
Even if it was a static dispatch, I'd think that it should still call `SubP.foo()`.
Why does the base protocol implementation get called at #2?

Also, why does inheriting from `BaseC` make a difference
(if in the `class SubC` line I remove `BaseC` or replace it with `BaseP`,
then it suddenly prints "SubP")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `subP1.foo()` or `subP2.foo()`, you are calling the `foo` that satisfies the protocol requirement `foo` in `BaseP`. (i.e. the method that *witnessed* `BaseP.foo`). **There can be only one such witness.**

The other important thing is that the `foo` requirement is not in `SubP`, but in `BaseP`. **The only requirement of `SubP` is that the conformer has to also conform to `BaseP`.**

In the case of `subP1`, `C` directly conforms to `SubP`. To resolve the only requirement of `SubP`, `C` has to also conform to `BaseP`. Now the compiler needs to figure which method can witness `foo`. There are two methods available, but the one from the `SubP` extension hides the one from the `BaseP` extension, so the one from the `SubP` extension is chosen to be the witness, so you see `SubP` printed.

In the case of `subP2`, the witness of `foo` is already decided when you conformed `BaseC` to `BaseP`. Here, there is only one choice - `foo` from the `BaseC` extension. When you later conformed `SubC` to `SubP`, the only requirement left is that `SubC` should also conform to `BaseP`. Well, you said `SubC` inherits from `BaseC`, so that's fine. The compiler is happy, and `foo` from the `BaseP` extension ends up being the witness.

Comment: I guess the key here (for me at least) is "the witness of `foo` is already decided when you conformed `BaseC` to `BaseP`". Although your explanation makes perfect sense, the consequences of this behavior still seem a bit surprising and confusing to me. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @imre Yes, that is the key. And the reason why it is decided so early, is because `foo` is a requirement of `BaseP`, not `SubP`.